# SQL Server 2005 after-install logon failed

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, installation

I've just installed SQL Server 2005 x64 SP3 on Windows 7 Professional.
I've chosen "Windows-based authentification scheme".
Then, i have a domain account, and i've added it to "Administrators" local user group.

The problem is: I can't login to SQL Server. Error is: "Login failed for user 'DOMAIN\User'. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error 18456)"

Comment: This question might be more appropriate for http://serverfault.com/ as it sounds like more of a sys-admin question rather than a programming or code problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing was: UAC.
I disabled it, restarted and the problem disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

There is a fix available for your problem.

See this MS KB [article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/925744) for detailed information about it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I re-installed which solved the issue. But during the new install I noticed that there was a provisioning screen which forces one to grant rights/privileges for the new user. The original installation was done using a different persons domain account.

If I'm not mistaken, you need to add the user using `sqlprov.exe` after the install. Or you could try and use Surface Area Configuration (something) to add a new Administrator.. or re-install

Answer (score 0):

Is your domain account member of the local Administrators group? It seems that's not the case. Verify it by running `net localgroup Administrators` from the command prompt and see if `DOMAIN\User` is listed as a member.

You can then either add yourself to the local Administrators group, or start any query tool of choice (SSMS, sqlcmd) as the local Administrator user (using 'Run As') and add yourself as a SQL administrator:

```
CREATE LOGIN [DOMAIN\User] FROM WINDOWS;
exec sp_addsrvrolemember 'DOMAIN\User', 'sysadmin';
```